# Restore files in geo redundant Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

We have an Azure Blob storage account which is geo redundant. For a reason we can't explain some files have been deleted over the night, we suspect an issue with the file provider we are using (This is an Umbraco application using https://github.com/idseefeld/UmbracoAzureBlobStorage).

We updated the package to the latest version and we hope it does not happen again. However, is it possible to retrieve the files from a secondary location, is there any snapshots?

Comment: Two suggestions

1. You can take snapshot for your blobs if that's what you need
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh488361.aspx

2. You shall turn on analytics/monitoring on your storage account, so you can tell who initiated the delete request if that happens again.
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-monitor-storage-account/

Answer (score 1):

> However, is it possible to retrieve the files from a secondary
>   location, is there any snapshots?

If the file is deleted from the primary location, in the next geo-replication cycle it will be removed from secondary location as well. So I don't think you will be able to recover the files from secondary location. You may find this blog post useful: https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-data/cloud-storage-replication-is-not-backup/.

One possible solution would be to reach out to Azure support and ask them if they can restore the deleted files for you. Typically if you reach out to them soon after the accidental deletes, they would be able to restore the files for you.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if we need to purchase a support plan on Azure for that kind of request?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. You can try under free support and see what they have to say. But please do provide what support said so that other folks can benefit.